# What does 'yield resource' in the Devise controllers do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I was looking through the Devise code and noticed that most of the controllers yield the resource being created.

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  # ...
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    # ...
```

This must be some sort of extendability feature but I don't really get how you would pass a block to to the controller action?

**Note:** This question is about how you would actually do it in the Rails request cycle, not about how blocks in Ruby work.

Comment: http://mudge.name/2011/01/26/passing-blocks-in-ruby-without-block.html

Comment: @Jonathan Right, but that still does not explain how you would pass a block to `Devise::RegistrationsController#create` in the first place. AFAIK it is called by the router.

Comment: You can pass a block to any method in Ruby if I'm not mistaken. Just try it. As long as it is the last argument

Comment: Yeah but that would only work if I instantiated the controller manually. This question is about how you would actually do in the rails request cycle, not about how blocks work.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's to allow subclasses to reuse the `create` implementation provided by devise, but being able to hook into the process.

For example you might have something like

```
class MyRegistrations < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
     super { |resource| ... }
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok. That explain also why it is written `yield resource if block_given?`, it will only call it if a variable is passed ... ?!

Comment: Yes @FabrizioBertoglio. Otherwise you will get a local jump error.

Comment: @max Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!