# Puma doesn't seem to be executing current codebase for devise user/registrations_controller.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, devise

I've Ctrl+C my Rails server and rebooted the machine, but Puma keeps running an old version of the code.

```
Redirected to http://printrdwn.com:3000/
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:17
  Role Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:17
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:17
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
```

On Line 17 Puma queries the Role Model. There is no reference to the Role Model in my code. Here is the users/registrations_controller.rb, which inherits devise:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super

    @team = Team.new(name: "Personal")
    TeamMember.create(user_id: current_user, team_id: @team.id, role_id: 1)
    @team.save
  end
end
```

In a past version of the user/registrations_controller I did reference Role in order to select the Administrator role, but that was unecessary. I've been trying to get the users/registrations_controller to create a Team and the current_user as a TeamMember, but then I realized my code didn't ever change with my corrections.

Comment: Have you setup your routes with `devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }`? You should also be passing a block to super like: `super do;  @team = Team.new(name: "Personal")... end` as the logic you are adding to the controller will be executed no matter if the record is valid or not.

Comment: And you are calling `@team.id` before you save the record which means that you're assigning `team_id: nil`

Comment: I have this in my routes `devise_for :users, controllers: {
        registrations: 'users/registrations'
      }` . I'll look into learning more about super. @max

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425850/what-does-yield-resource-in-the-devise-controllers-do

Comment: I updated my controller to ` super do |user| ... end' I also changed `Team.new` to `Team.create`. Then I realized the current_user will not work, because the update session block happens afterwards, so I changed `current_user` to `user.id`. Now It's creating Team and TeamMember.

Comment: Devise yields the user being created to the block so you can always get it through the block argument `super do |user| ... end`.

Comment: @max If you want to answer the question I will mark it solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pass a block to super so that the team is only created if the user is actually persisted:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super do |user|
      @team = Team.new(name: "Personal")
      @team.members.new(user: user, role_id: 1)
      @team.save
     end
  end
end
```

And building the record off the association will make sure that Rails actually saves both records in the same transaction. Passing ids explicitly is a code smell and in this case actually a bug as `@team.id` is nil as the record was not saved.